# How we set full file path and file name in file uploader controler in asp.net c#

Tags: java, asp.net

I have file uploader and two button (button1 and button2).I want full all file path on button1 click if there is 1 file upload and more. And on button2 click I want to save these files in our folder.
thanks

Comment: PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/AdminDocument/") + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(AdminFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName));

Comment: second thing I do                                                                                         File = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(AdminFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);                                                                                              System.IO.File.Copy(File, "Server.MapPath(~/AdminDocument/)" + datAdminDocument.Rows[0].ToString());